# Comparing the cosine similarities of the same word representations, from two separate models (vector spaces)

Tags: nlp, word2vec, bert

I am comparing the cosine similarities of word representations derived from a BERT model and also from a static Word2Vec model.

I understand that the vector spaces of the two models are inherently different due to the dimensionality of BERT (768) and Word2Vec (300). Essentially I am trying to find a way to compare the two cosine similarity measurements between the same words but from two different models.

I also have a set of user-determined similarity scores between the words, e.g., 'vaccinate' - 'inoculate' = 8.99. I was thinking of using this as a scaling factor for the two similarities so each cosine similarity from the vector space would then be scaled by the same amount.

I essentially want to quantitatively compare the cosine similarity scores between two models' representations for the same words. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. So you have multiple pairs of words, and for every pair you have the score based on BERT and the score based on Word2vec, right? If so you could consider a lot of things: correlation (Person or Spearman); regression evaluation measures like MAE, MSE, etc. You could also plot the difference, see if there's a link between this difference and the frequency,... It all depends what is your goal.